# Select() does not work inside ThenInclude()

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying to retrieve a `movie` object that has a `screenings` list. Every object in `screenings` has a `theater` object that in turn has a `screenings` list. I am trying to get rid of that `screenings` list in `theater` so I created a `theaterDTO` model.

[what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIzOl.png)

```
    var x = _context.Movies
                .Where(m => movieId == m.Id)
                .Include(m => m.Screenings)
```

this results in `screening` list being retrieved multiple times: in `movie` object and in every `theater` object in `movie.theaters`

Here's the `Screening` class:

```
public class Screening : BaseEntity
    {
        public Theater Theater { get; set; }
        public Movie Movie { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }    
        public Screening()
        {
            Bookings = new List<Booking>();
        }
    }
```

`Movie`:

```
public class Movie : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string Dir { get; set; }
        public string Pic { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Screening> Screenings { get; set; }
        public Movie()
        {
            Screenings = new List<Screening>();
        }
    }
```

`Theater`:

```
public class Theater : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Screening> Screenings { get; set; }
        public Theater()
        {
            Screenings = new List<Screening>();
        }
    }
```

`TheaterDTO`:

```
public class TheaterDTO 
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

the function:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("{movieId}")]
    public Movie GetMovieById(Guid movieId)
    {
        return _context.Screenings
            .Where(m => movieId == m.Id)
            .Select(x => new TheaterDTO
            {
                Name = x.Theater.Name,
                Address = x.Theater.Address
            }).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: `Theater` isn't a list, it's a single object. What are you trying to select?

Comment: @Blindy There's a many-to-many relationship between `movies` and `theaters` and `screenings` is the bridge table. I'm trying to select a movie object with a list of `screenings`. Every object in `screenings` has a `theater`. I want that `theater` to only have two columns and omit the rest.

Comment: Can you post your Screening  class pls?

Comment: @Serge I've added the class

Comment: Thanks, sorry could you add Theater and Movie too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define a MovieDTO:

```
public class MovieDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Dir { get; set; }
    public string Pic { get; set; }
    public List<ScreeningDTO> Screenings { get; set; }
}

public class ScreeningDTO
{
    public TheaterDTO Theater { get; set; } 
}

public class TheaterDTO
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

the take data like this:

```
var x = _context.Movies
            .Where(m => movieId == m.Id)
            .Include(m => m.Screenings)
               .ThenInclude(s => s.Theater)
            .Where(p => p.Id == movieId)
            .Select(p => new MovieDTO {
                      Name = p.Name,
                      Body = p.Body,
                      Dir = p.Dir,
                      Pic = p.Pic,
                      Screening = p.Screenings.Select(x => new ScreeningDTO {
                                     Theater = new TheaterDTO {
                                        Name = x.Theater.Name,
                                        Address = x.Theater.Address
                                    }
                       }).ToList()
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. throws this error: `CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type "System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Data.Entities.TheaterDTO> Screening>>" to "Data.Entities.Movie"`

Comment: ok maybe the edited version works @user321

Comment: slightly different error: `CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type "System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<<anonymous type: string Name, string Address>> Screening>>" to "Data.Entities.Movie"`

Comment: oops, I forgot to add `ToList`. check again @user321

Comment: this time it's: `CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type "System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string Name, string Address>> Screening>>" to "Data.Entities.Movie"`

Comment: ok then you can fix it by defining a MovieDTO

Comment: I posted the whole answer, hope this works

Comment: thanks! it works. `.FirstOrDefault()` needed at the end

Comment: Please note that the Includes have no function here.